# ng2-validation not working in Angular2 angular-seed

Tags: angular, angular-seed

I am trying to integrate [ng2-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-validation) in my Angular2 [angular-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) based project. I have followed the steps mentioned in the ng2-validation documentation but i am getting following error. Please help me in this regard.

```
"(SystemJS) Unexpected token <
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-validation/dist/directives/range-length.js:13:10)
        at eval (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-validation/dist/directives/range-length.js:43:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-validation/dist/directives/range-length.js:44:3)
    Evaluating http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-validation/dist/
    Evaluating http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-validation/dist/directives/range-length.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-validation/dist/directives.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-validation/dist/index.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:5555/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:5555/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:5555/app/main.js"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this configuration for your files array in `karma.conf.js`:

```
{
  pattern: 'node_modules/ng2-validators/*.js',
  included: false,
  watched: false
},
{
  pattern: 'node_modules/ng2-validators/**/*.js',
  included: false,
  watched: false
}
```

Based on ng2-validators version , you can use configuration as specified in the link :  https://github.com/Nightapes/ng2-validators/issues/11